# How to get Auth-Token in openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I installed OpenStack liberty in VM(Virutal  Box) and I am trying to get Aut-token and I got some method to get Auth-token from stack overflow so i used that command

**curl -d '{"auth":{"passwordCredentials":{"username": "can", "password": "mypassword"}}}' -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost/v2.0/tokens**

but it is not giving any responses,it just shows

>

in command prompt.could any one explain what is wrong with my steps..

Answer (score 1):

The `>` character that you see suggests a copy/paste error.  You are probably pasting a newline in the middle of your curl command.

The token request you are passing to keystone is fine, however in most cases keystone will be running on port 5000, which you will need to specify in the URL (e.g. `http://localhost:5000/v2.0/tokens`).

Here is an example of what you should get:

```
# curl -sd '{"auth":{"passwordCredentials":{"username": "admin", "password": "password"}}}' -H "Content-type: application/json" http://192.168.113.57:5000/v2.0/tokens | python -m json.tool
{
    "access": {
        "metadata": {
            "is_admin": 0,
            "roles": []
        },
        "serviceCatalog": [],
        "token": {
            "audit_ids": [
                "Yk4h80jJTe6jiGKzXFge9Q"
            ],
            "expires": "2016-08-08T03:06:40Z",
            "id": "gAAAAABXp06AlKkt_fxEuDbjW19h4nvwC-7rgEr9Mw4abtc_uUGTm4HSGukUzRf5JYS8Q6J-fexDVLTtA7doaUzkvnLlLSFEfjW0e4IVq3V0rccvU9fLErNcNcWWJNx3pPM1fjBHEvGOlYvwEFmUUXhxl9VHKqO_DQ",
            "issued_at": "2016-08-07T15:06:40.000000Z"
        },
        "user": {
            "id": "732a8637a18b4e91ac9d8a95a8477e05",
            "name": "admin",
            "roles": [],
            "roles_links": [],
            "username": "admin"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya. I will try this Thank u so much

Comment: I tried the above command you specified and it worked also and I got the output and I used id   as Auth-token for PUT method

Comment: curl -i -X PUT "X-Auth-Token:bcced26a96304e8197fa85e110df9aa2"                  http://169.0.0.11/dashboard/project/containers/test/mymusic                                                                                            but its saying that                                                                             Could not resolve host: X-AUTH-TOKEN                                       HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY          
can  you help me to solve this problem please

Answer (score 1):

To get the token using curl command:

```
curl http://<controller_ip>:5000/v2.0/tokens \
-X POST \
-d '{"auth":{"tenantName":"demo", "passwordCredentials":{"username":"demo", "password":"*****"}}}' \
-H "Content-type: application/json" | python -m json.tool
```